# Add a button in an IndexedContainer with Grid Vaadin

Tags: jakarta-ee, vaadin7

Currently I have defined an IndexedContainer with many properties of type String. I have added this Indexed Container to a Vaadin 7 Grid and It Worked properly.

Now I want to make one of my columns clickable. For that I have created the following code (actually a small portion of the code):

```
modifyReportButton = new Button();

modifyReportButton.setIcon(IconUtil.MODIFY_16PX_ICON.getIcon());
modifyReportButton.setDescription("Modifier"); 
modifyReportButton.setStyleName(Runo.BUTTON_LINK);
modifyReportButton.setWidth("30px");//ticket7021                         
modifyReportButton.addListener(modifyReportFromExplorerClick);                       
modifyReportButton.addClickListener(modifyReportFromExplorerClick);
modifyReportButton.setData(lightReport);
item.getItemProperty("modify").setValue(modifyReportButton);
```

The problem is that the button is not displayed in the grid at all. Here is a snapshot:

[Grid with Button problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toYEZ.png)

In fact, I have to do it this way. I mean I have to use an IndexedContainer inside a grid, otherwise I will have to change many related classes (the project is so big and we are not able to allocate a high cost for maintenance).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `GeneratedPropertyContainer` to add the button column and a `ButtonRenderer`.

```
// Generate button caption column
GeneratedPropertyContainer gpc = new GeneratedPropertyContainer(yourIndexedContainer);
gpc.addGeneratedProperty("modify", new PropertyValueGenerator<String>() {

    @Override
    public String getValue(Item item, Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
        return "Modify Report";
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> getType() {
        return String.class;
    }
});

grid.setContainerDataSource(gpc);
grid.getColumn("modify").setRenderer(new ButtonRenderer(modifyReportFromExplorerClick()));
```

More info in the Grid Component doc https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/components/components-grid.html